# ScriptResource & WebResource Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, webresource.axd, scriptresource.axd

Here is a picture of the errors:
[image: errors]

Here is a copy of my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BaseConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=BRYAN-PC;Initial Catalog=Base;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>

    <sessionState
              mode="InProc"
              stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"
              sqlConnectionString="Data Source=BRYAN-PC;Initial Catalog=Base;Integrated Security=True"
              cookieless="false"
              timeout="500000"
      />
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <!-- Prevent excess code to clutter source -->
    <pages buffer="true" validateRequest="true" enableViewState="true"/>
 </system.web>

</configuration>
```

I am curious as to why these errors are happening. The only ajax I have going on is the jsTree pluggin which originally wasn't showing these errors. I set up the jsTree plugin to use `[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]` to talk to the code behind.

Can anyone shed some light on how to fix these errors? The code or it's functionality isn't broken but these errors clearly show that I am missing something.

IF anyone requires additional information, please let me know. Thanks!

EDIT: I forgot to mention that it didn't matter what page I was on. The errors shows up all the time.

EDIT2: I am not even using any AJAX Toolkit things at all so I removed it and the ScriptResource issues went away but not my WebResource Issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebResource normally point to those JavaScript files you embed in your dll when doing build? I will verify those files are built correctly (you have to set up build option in property window as "embed resource").

You should also be able to figure out which javascript file it's complaining by reading the error line.